# Does int sum = func(1) + func(2) cause undefined behavior if func() modifies a global variable

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

Inspired by this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior), I am wondering whether the below snippet causes UB as both `add_func()` and `mul_func()` could modify `counter` concurrently and in an unspecified order:

```
int counter = 0;

int mul_func(int x) {
  counter *= x;
  x = counter;
  return x;
}

int add_func(int x) {
  counter += x;
  x = counter;
  return x;
}

int main(void) {
  int sum = add_func(3) + mul_func(2);
}
```

If so, does it help if I add mutex to them?:

```
int counter = 0;

pthread_mutex_d mtx;

int mul_func(int x) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
  counter *= x;
  x = counter;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
  return x;
}

int add_func(int x) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
  counter += x;
  x = counter;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
  return x;
}

int main(void) {
  pthread_mutex_init(&mtx);
  int sum = add_func(3) + mul_func(2);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mtx);
}
```

While the result can be non-deterministic (as the case of many multi-threading procedures), does the "unsequenced" nature still cause UB even if there is no data race?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Is func() + func() undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18907342) - the function calls make this indeterminately-sequenced, not unsequenced.

Comment: @PeterCordes I actually found this link before posting my question. Do you mean to say the answer is "no, it does NOT cause UB"? I have the feeling that the link you post avoids a very important part--his func() does not modify a global variable. Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374264/is-cout-synchronized-thread-safe), `std::cout` is thread-safe, so the case in your link is not as special as this one I think.

Comment: why does mul_func adds and add_func multiplies ?

Comment: @PeterCordes That question is about C++. C has its own rules.

Comment: @CemPolat because of my silly mistake...just reversed them...

Comment: While the order of the function calls might be indeterminate, or left for the implementation (don't have the details), the behavior itself is well-defined. Even though the result is indeterminate, there's no real UB (I think). If the order is important, split the expression into multiple sub-expressions, storing intermediate results in temporary variables.

Comment: "could modify counter concurrently" No they could not, it is not allowed by the standard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude did you check the link in my question? It basically says `int a = ++i + ++i` causes UB, if so, I kind of think my code causes UB too (at least the 1st snippet should)

Comment: Your question and the question you link to have different answers.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39900605/19634193), it is possible the CPU has some implied sort-of "multi-threading" feature. But I am not sure if the answer is factually accurate.

Comment: @WeijunZhou: Good point, looking for a C Q&A about indeterminately-sequenced vs. unsequenced.  [Evaluation Order of C Language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58957637) refers to the fact that function calls aren't unsequenced, but isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Both entering a function and returning from a function are sequence points, so there is nothing "unsequenced" about this code. The fact that it's valid does not mean it's a good pattern to use, but I am sure you know that already :-)

Comment: @PeterCordes do you mean the introduction of function calls makes it well-defined?

Comment: Function calls do not behave the same way built-in operators do. The standard says so, but various SO posts usually don't, so you cannot always infer that bit of information by reading SO posts. You need to read the actual standard or at least a good textbook.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko emmm I try very hard to find another construct in which I can avoid function calls but still use mutex in a statement...but can find none--perhaps this is exactly how the standard makes it self-consistent...

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI do you know which section of standard says so?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: Yes.  Compilers aren't allowed to interleave function bodies after inlining.  (Except in ways that don't change the behaviour, *as if* it did one then the other).  Code in separate functions is at worst indeterminately-sequenced (like in this case) not unsequenced, so the compiler gets a choice of which to call first.

Comment: @PeterCordes there is an answer that thinks the code is still undefined, but due to different reason, what do you think about that?..

Comment: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p10

Comment: C11 `mtx_lock` or `pthread_mutex_lock` are both function calls, so they introduce sequencing.  And using them in a way that sequences anything else would by definition require sequencing, e.g. with GNU C statement-expressions like `int tmp = {mtx_lock(&L); counter*=x; mtx_unlock(&L); counter; } + {mtx_lock(&L); counter+=x; mtx_unlock(&L); counter; };`.  I'm actually not sure what the sequencing rules are for statement-expressions, whether the bodies of the two are unsequenced wrt. each other even though there's sequencing between the statements inside each one.  Probably sequenced.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI  how about `int a = i++ + func() + ++i;`? Does the sequence point help to make it well-defined per your understanding of the standard or a good textbook?

Comment: *there is an answer that thinks the code is still undefined* - Where?  Are you talking about 
Christian Stieber's answer?  I think it missed the point of the question, because it doesn't clearly explain that they're not unsequenced, only indeterminately sequenced.  As it says, it's up to the compiler *which order* to call the functions.  But there is an order, it's just not specified by the code.  There isn't UB in your code because the two side-effects on `counter` are in separate functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: How do you figure `++i + ++i` is well defined? It modifies `i` twice without sequencing. Even `i + ++i` or `++i + i` would have undefined behavior, let alone `++i + ++i`.

Comment: No it does not. What exact words in that paragraph make you think it might?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: `int a = i++ + func() + ++i;` has UB since nothing sequences `i++` vs. `++i`.  They can't overlap with the body of `func()`, but the "sequence point" on entering the function doesn't require left-to-right order or anything.  Operator precedence for combining the results of multiple expressions is separate from evaluation order of the expressions. Read [Evaluation Order of C Language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58957637) which I linked earlier about how multiple orders are possible for `foo() + (x += 2)` (but without UB even if `foo()` modifies `x`)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI 
port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p10

Comment: I don´t understand why you are telling me that there is such a link. I sent it to you in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed up to the compiler do decide the order in which it wants to call your functions. It will call both before the addition, but that's about all you know.

Your mutex doesn't do anything; these are for synchronizing threads, not forcing your compile to evaluate things in the order you want it. You code doesn't do things in parallel, it just does it in unspecified order.

The correct way to enforce an ordering would be something like

```
const int left=add_func(3);
const int right=mul_func(2);
int sum=left+right;
```

That way, the compiler has no choice but to call the functions in the order you're providing.

Update: so, as suggested in one of the comments, let me emphasize the wording a bit. Your code is not "undefined behavior" as per language definitions; you're actually getting one of two possible results, which are very well defined: one result appears if the compiler decides to call add_func first and mul_func second, while the other appears if the compiler likes the other calling order better.

The order in which the two functions are called is "unspecified", but they are always called one after the other, never in parallel. Any optimization that the compiler or the CPU might add that introduce some degree of parallelism will not change that; you'll always get one of the two possible results.

Just think about it from a different angle: if the compiler (or the CPU, or god) would add some random parallelism that would require YOU to take certain precautions, such unexpected changes to program behavior would break every software.
There is a reason why optimizations always use terminology like not changing "observable behavior".

And yes, C++ allows certain optimizations to change "observable behavior", but that's explicitly laid out in the language specification, and not something that a compiler (or CPU) would just do on a whim.

Comment: My question is not about forcing order, you may refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39900605/19634193), my take is that it means CPU can have some implicit parallelism, which is the underlying reason why `int a = ++i + ++i` is marked as undefined.

Comment: No, that is not the underlying reason.

CPUs doing things in parallel are still required to not change the behavior of the program. Same with the compiler -- yes, it can make things parallel, but it will be its job to make sure the two functions don't get into conflict. Your example is undefined because, again, the unspecified order of argument evaluation.

Comment: which one is called argument in "the unspecified order of argument evaluation."? Do you mean `3` and `2` are arguments? or?

Comment: The results of the expressions `add_func(3)` and `mul_func(2)` are the arguments to the `+` operator. Just because you don't know which is evaluated first, doesn't mean they might be evaluated in parallel. They happen sequentially, it's just that the standard doesn't specify which of two possible orders are used.

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if it said explicitly that there's no UB, the function bodies are *indeterminately sequenced*.  The OP is worried that they're *unsequenced* like `i++ + ++i` would be.